# How to add image property in my model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I just started learning asp.net MVC. How can I add pictures?

My Person model has:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }                
}
```

Comment: do you want to post image to controller or you want to show it on your View? It's 2 different situations

Comment: He said he just started to learn asp.net so i dont think he understands that yet :)

Comment: @Mlle im guessing you are using the default Web Application with MVC project?

Comment: @john Yes im using the default project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok if you are using the default web application with mvc this would be one way to do it:

add a property for image url to your model

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```

save it and in Models > Identity Model add DbSet for your model

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        //ADD JUST THIS LINE
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Rebuild your solution and add a controller also thick Generate views and the others(Reference script libraries, Use a layout page)

[image]

then in your Index view of the controller find this line

```
<td>
     DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)
</td>
```

and change it with this

```
<td>
    <img src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" />
</td>
```

then when you go to create new person you just post any image url you want in the image input

[image]

for example this url http://mywindowshub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/user-account.jpg

and on index it will look like this:
[image]

you just resize the image for your needs and you`re done.
So i hope this helps you.

EDIT:

If you want to add your images from local folder, say you have a folder name images in Content, when you go to create new person in your image input text,  you enter the image url like this:  ~/Content/images/ImageName.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is enough for what i need now :D

Comment: Probably is better to rename your `Image` property into `ImagePath` or something like this. Just to get rid of every piece of ambiguity. Great explication for a new guy.

Comment: But if it is image from resource?

Comment: And if I need to display checbox, then how to define this in model?